# Set EC2 instance Root Device type as SSD

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am creating EC2 instances using AWS. I am able to attach extra SSD drives using this config.

```
'BlockDeviceMappings' => array(
    array(
        'VirtualName' => 'data_volume',
        'DeviceName' => '/dev/sdg',
        'Ebs' => array(
            'VolumeSize' => 2,
            'VolumeType' => 'gp2'
        )
    ),
```

But I'm not able to make the root device an SSD one. I tried **VolumeType** and **RootDeviceType** parameters but they didn't worked.

Any solution for this?

Comment: You will need to use an instance backed AMI, instead of EBS backed.

Comment: Changing the AMI did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create ec2 instances with an EBS SSD root volume from the console. I typically use the Ruby SDK, like so:

```
ec2.instances.create(:image_id => 'image', :key_name => 'key', :instance_type => 'class', :security_groups => 'group', :count => 1, :block_device_mappings => [{:device_name => '/dev/sda1', :ebs => {:volume_size => 10, :volume_type => 'gp2'}}])
```